# What are the performance numbers in the Vue devtools next to the components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-devtools

Does anyone have an insights or a resource for a feature in the Vue Dev Tools? On the components pane it shows my components and then these little red and yellow squares with what I am assuming is the component's performance.

When I first load the app they don't appear but for example I update an text input component which validates its own format when a user types in a new value. This updates a Vuex store and/or a computed property but what confuses me is why the whole thing lights up like an angry Christmas tree. The unrelated components show these performance numbers.

When I check the mutations in the Vuex history I am only updating the one item.

I did my best to search around before asking, but was unable to find anything for this feature. There is not a lot of good resources in general for Vue dev tools which is a little surprising since the usually have great documentation.

[image]

Comment: This is the time a component takes to render IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vue DevTools measures the duration of some of the component's lifecycle hooks (including `created`, `mounted`, and `destroyed`). It displays a colored performance tag next to a component if the duration exceeds a threshold to flag potential performance issues ([source](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/blob/7012ebd843bf7646307b7f3a3fa9a4e93150a7d0/packages/app-backend-core/src/perf.ts#L130)):

| Duration | Color | Example | Performance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <= 10ms | green | - | Good (?) |
| > 10ms | yellow | [image: yellow tag] | Needs improvement |
| > 30ms | red | [image: red tag] | Poor |

*I couldn't reproduce the green tag, but I think that might be intentionally hidden to avoid unnecessary noise.*

Hovering the colored tags reveals a tooltip that shows the name of the associated lifecycle hook for the measurement:

[image: tooltip with one measurement]

And there can be multiple measurements in one tooltip:

[image: tooltip with multiple measurements]

These tags can be disabled via *Global Settings* > *Performance Monitoring* (after disabling, you might have to restart Vue DevTools to clear the tags):

[image: perf setting toggle]